# Keeping question updated and reflecting user comments

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833541/making-friends-around-a-circular-table) some time ago that's been getting a decent amount of attention. In short, the question involves finding the value of terms of a sequence, and crucially, each term can be upper-bounded (by either checking all possibilities, or by randomized trials). When writing the original question, I provided a list of known upper bounds, but this list has had to be updated multiple times as people pointed out better bounds in the comments. What's a good way to keep my question updated to reflect these comments? Here are the options I've considered:

1. Change question every time a relevant comment is posted: bumps my question and leads to a long edit history
2. Link to some external dynamic content that I can update: susceptible to link rot if I stop updating the content in the future
3. Transfer upper bounds to a CW answer: bounds might be buried beneath better answers - although not an issue now since there are only two answers

Do you have any other ideas? What are some good ways in which you've dealt with a situation like this?

Comment: Looking at your post, and the efforts of many users through links and comments, as well as your ongoing modifications., I do think it may be very appropriate to make the question itself a CW post, (which automatically makes answers CW too.)  But I don't the the Q&A nature of the site legitimates a post in progress indefinitely.

Comment: One final idea would be to transfer the comment section of your answer  to a chat room, if you're interested in maintaining a discussion with other users about the question.  Just don't keep updating the question, nor your answer, because I believe doing either will keep bumping your post to the main page.

Comment: @amWhy two questions 1) If I make a post community wiki, do updates to the post continue to bump it to the main page? 2) For your first comment, would you suggest that I explicitly state that I am no longer updating the question, and ask users to look at comments for updates? (The type of situation I'm trying to avoid is someone working hard for some time on a given case of my problem only to discover that a better result has been shown in the comments.)

Comment: Once the discussion gets too long; it is usually best to have modify the question to something that is more easily answered. You can then ask the original one in chat. This way you can spend time defining exactly what you mean. Its also possible to use the chat to formulate the best way to ask the question if there is not enough knowledge in chat at the time to answer it completely.